# Can't resize Xubuntu partition using Virtual Box / Gparted

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, gparted, partitioning, resize

I had created a virtual machine **Xubuntu 18.04.1**, using **Virtual Box 6.0** (on **Windows 10 x64**), initially with **10 Gb** of space.

I needed to resize it to **20 Gb** through the **Windows** command:

`.\VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\Users\user\VirtualBox VMs\xubuntu\xubuntu.vdi" --resize 20000`

Virtual Box is showing the correct space:

[image]

But when using **Gparted**, it's not recognizing the unallocated space:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a procedure that should do it for you. https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/how-to-increase-virtualbox-disk-size-for-dynamically-allocated-disks

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy in virtualbox and call it a clone
create a dynamic drive of the size you want and use the following command.

The --existing will allow the original to be copied into it.

vboxmanage clonemedium disk /media/jack/VirtualBoxVM/BlackArch.vdi /media/jack/ExtraStorage/BlackArch_Clone/BlackArch_Clone.vdi --existing